# Usage of Autofilter with dates

Tags: excel, vba, date, autofilter

I'm trying to filter a column of dates and select only data between two dates that i load in two variables alfaDA and alfaA
I did the following code :

```
Dim alfaDa, alfaA As String
alfaDa = DateofDayDA
alfaA = DateofDayA
Dim DA, A As Date
Dim ldateDA, ldateA As Long
'alfa = Cells(1, 10)
DA = Format(alfaDa, "short date")
A = Format(alfaA, "short date")
ldateDA = DA
ldateA = A
Sheets("venduto").Select
Range("A1").AutoFilter
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & ldateDA, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & ldateA
```

what happen is that not always the two long variables ldateDA and ladateA contain long integere numbers and so the autofilter fail.
Any clue ?
thanks

Comment: Welcome. Quick note about `Dim` in VBA: `Dim DA, A As Date` means that `DA` is now a variant. Same goes for `ldateDA` and `alfaDa`. You need to do `Dim DA As Date, A As Date`. This is not an answer to the question, just good to know.

Comment: Thanks braX..i think you answered my question indirectly